# Can someone tell me how to put a $ with numbers?

Tags: sql

I have a query where I have to use the `convert` function to return the unitprice as a decimal with 2 digits to the right of the decimal and a $ to the left of the number.

For example : 10 should be $10.00

Can anyone tell me how do i insert the $?

this is my code so far

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, UnitPrice, 1) AS varchartotal
FROM dbo.[Order Details]
```

Comment: Do you have a sqlfiddle for us to use / test against?  I am sure i could make one.... to test with.

Comment: This type of thing should probably be done in the UI. Surely wherever you're displaying this data has a way to format a value as a currency?

Comment: (Why) does it have to be sql?

Comment: You cannot use this syntax in mysql (in that way, in any case), you should eliminate the mysql tag: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/charset-convert.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of thing should **always** be done in the UI. Surely wherever you're displaying this data has a way to format a value as a currency, and for a certain culture (what happens when you need to display Euros or Yen or something with a different symbol?).

That said, this is a problem that simple string concatenation can solve:

```
SELECT '$' + CONVERT(varchar, UnitPrice, 1) AS varchartotal
FROM dbo.[Order Details]
```

Note: I don't approve of this ever being used in a production environment.

**EDIT:** There's some confusion whether you mean MySQL or SQL Server. If you're using MySQL, you can't use `CONVERT` here, but you can cast as CHAR instead:

```
SELECT CONCAT('$', CAST(UnitPrice AS CHAR(20))) AS varchartotal
FROM dbo.[Order Details]
```

Comment: are you sure you can convert to `varchar` in `mySQL`?

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky: I didn't see this was tagged with MySQL. The `CONVERT` function here clearly looks like T-SQL.

Comment: just asking as the question was tagged with `mysql`

Comment: I think it's the user asking who is wrong thinking that this syntax is valid in mysql

Comment: very sorry i did not mean to tag mysql it is supposed to be sql